# .htaccess causing session/cookie issues in chrome

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, session, cookies

Ok guy's i've had a problem that I've been obsessing over for days and still can't find a solution. basically what is happening is.. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework and when I use .htaccess to remove the index.php from the bootstrap, Only in chrome does the session not set. It works fine everywhere else. If I do it without the .htaccess, just using say mysite.com/index.php/controller it works fine.

I'm so stumped and tried so many different solutions/fixes etc. and nothing. I can't find anyone else at all with this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Who would thunk this entire issue was caused by a missing file in the head, favicon.gif!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at the end was so obvious, the problem was in my htaccess, I leave a comment in case it can help to anyone. I was caching html, css, etc. If you put this at the end of your .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$"> 
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate" 
</filesMatch> 
</ifModule>
```

you'll get your session ok. This is because for example:

- You enter to your site, and you are not logged. But you already served a page view for users not logged in.
- Then you'll log in
- But when you return to your previous page, you'll see the same as previous page, as if you were not logged. This is because the browser show you the previous and cached page, even if your session exist...But if you reload you will see the correct page.